# Non-Conforming Array Limits with Matrix Operations in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I'm running into a `non-conformable arrays` error that doesn't make much sense to me.

I have a vector of `scores` that is n=37k elements long. I make an identity matrix of size n x n:

`mat <- diag(length(scores))`

I then try to multiply this by the `scores` vector and get a non-conformable arrays error.

`mat <- mat * scores`

`Error in mat * scores : non-conformable arrays`

On checking the dimensions, everything seems ok:

```
dim(mat)
[1] 37000 37000

length(scores)
[1] 37000
```

If I test this with a shorter array, it seems to work without errors:

```
test.scores <- scores[1:100]
test.mat <- diag(length(test.scores))
test.mat <- test.mat * test.scores
```

Is this a memory/size limitation or is there something else going on? My ultimate aim is a matrix with the `scores` along the diagonal.

Comment: `*` isn't standard matrix multiplication. It is the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). You probably want `%*%`

Comment: @John Coleman That returns a 1 column matrix. I want an n x n matrix, with the `score` values on the diagonal

Comment: Just assign scores to the diagonal using the `diag` function. `diag(mat) <- scores` should work. See `?diag` for details.

Comment: When running `scores <- as.numeric(1:37e3); mat <- diag(length(scores)); mat <- mat * scores` I get no error (R 4.1.1).

Comment: If all you want is a diagonal matrix with `scores` along the diagonal, why not skip the identity matrix step and just use `mat <- diag(scores)` to begin with?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you, that's what I'm trying. I'm currently getting an `nrow value (too large or NA)` error and trying to troubleshoot

Comment: if `scores` has length 37K then your `mat` would be seriously sparse. Perhaps you can use a sparse matrix package. Or -- use a different algorithm for whatever it is that you are ultimately doing that doesn't need to wrap 37K numbers in 1.3 billion zeros. This seems like a likely [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835).

Comment: @JohnColeman I'll look into a different package, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I think I will need to use a sparse matrix as it is the form necessary to define constraints in the linear optimization problem I'm working on. I don't think it's an XY problem, as the setup works with smaller problem sets. The real problem I'm trying to solve with this question is why the approach does not work past a set size threshold